# Bootstrap Collapse CSS Transition Property

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to recreate the bootstrap v5 collapse functionality, for learning purpose. Once the collapse button is clicked, the collapse class is removed. Collapsing class is added and transition happens.

[Bootstrap Reference Link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/collapse)

But due to display:none property, the transition is not working. How is that working in bootstrap?

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".toggle").on("click", function() {
    $("#content").css('height', '400px');
    $("#content").addClass("collapsing");
    $("#content").removeClass('collapse');
  });
})
```

```css
.collapse:not(.show) {
  display: none;
}

.collapsing {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 5s ease;
}

#content {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="toggle">Toggle</button>

<div id="content" class="collapse">
  <p>Content Goes Here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It’s because of the collapsing state. They only add display none after collapsing. So you have open state where you can see the content, you can collapsing state where the transition happens, then you have collapsed state with display none

Comment: Just so you know, Twitter 5+ no longer uses JQuery

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working code as expected.

Below codes works well on my chrome browser and [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dnj5wLm8/)

But Stackoverflow the collapse action is abrupt.

```js
jQuery(function(){

jQuery(".toggle").on("click", function () {
    jQuery(".content").removeClass("collapse");
    jQuery(".content").addClass("collapsing");
    if (jQuery(".content").hasClass("show")) {

        jQuery(".content").css('height', '100px'); // need to set the height
        setTimeout(() => {

            jQuery(".content").css('height', ""); // need to reset the height
            jQuery(".content").removeClass("show");
        })

        return;
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
        jQuery(".content").css('height', '100px');
        jQuery(".content").addClass("show");
    })
})

jQuery(".content").on('transitionend', function () {
    console.log("transitionend")
    jQuery(".content").addClass("collapse");
    jQuery(".content").css('height', "");
    jQuery(".content").removeClass("collapsing");
});

})
```

```css
.collapse:not(.show){
    display:none;
}
.collapsing{
    height:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition: height 2s;
}

.para{
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin:5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <button class="toggle">Toggle</button>
    <div class="content collapse">
        <p class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque, cumque. Exercitationem neque debitis reprehenderit totam eius, esse magni quas, quis ratione animi tenetur earum accusantium explicabo eaque at doloremque delectus.</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's not abrupt for me. It transitions over the 2s interval as defined.